# how to show only the paypal component not other fundings like giro?

Tags: reactjs

how can I only show the paypal button not other payments buttons ?

code:

```
 
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={{
          currency: 'EUR',
          "disable-funding": "card,bancontact",
          "client-id": "xxx"
        }}>
          <PayPalButtons
            createOrder={async (data, actions) => {
              try {
                return await fetchData();
              } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
                return e;
              }
            }}
            onError={err => console.log(err)}
            onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
              try {
                const d = await capture(data.orderID);
                console.log(d);
                if(d.status === 'COMPLETED') {
                  setSuccess(true);
                } else {
                  setModalMessage(true);
                  setErrorText(d?.error ?? 'Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.');
                }
                return d;
              } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
              }
            
            }}
          />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
```

I am very thankful for your help. can anyone explain me how can I remove all buttons except the first one ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use the `fundingSource` property you have more info in https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default